# Spring random cron expression

Tags: java, spring, cron, scheduler

I want to have a job executed each 1 hour.
I have 4 pods running in kubernetes and I'm using this expression: `0 0 */1 * * *`

Current situation is that all pods execute the job the first minute of each hour.

I want to randomize the expression so that each pod will execute the job each hour but at random minute between 0-10.

In spring there is a random.int function so I used it: `0 ${random.int[0,5]} */1 * * *` but it executed the job each 2 minutes.

Comment: I guess the `${random.int[0,5]}` will only called once where the sceduler is created, If you start your application a gain, it wil generate a new random value

Comment: Do you want the executions to be at 01:05, then 02:03, then 03:04 and so on? Or do you want executions like 01:09, then 02:09, with the minute being random, decided once on startup?

Comment: If you have 4 instances, don't you want one of the pods to execute the job every hour instead of randomizing the execution? You can achieve that with e.g. shedlock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe give this a try:

```
0 $(expr $RANDOM \% 11) * * * *
```

***$(expr $RANDOM % 11)*** generates a random number between 0 and 10. *$RANDOM* is a built-in shell variable in Unix-like systems that generates a random integer

Good Luck!